# How can I get "docker-compose scale" to use the latest image for any additional instances created?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my project, I have a number of micro-services that rely upon each other. I am using Docker Compose to bring everything up in the right order.

During development, when I write some new code for a container, the container will need to be restarted, so that the new code can be tried. Thus far I've simply been using a restart of the whole thing, thus:

```
docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d
```

That works fine, but bringing everything down and up again takes ~20 seconds, which will be too long for a live environment. I am therefore looking into various strategies to ensure that micro-services may be rebooted individually with no interruption at all.

My first approach, which nearly works, is to scale up the service to reboot, from one instance to two. I then programmatically reset the reverse proxy (Traefik) to point to the new instance, and then when that is happy, I `docker stop` on the old one.

My scale command is the old variety, since I am using Compose 1.8.0. It looks like this:

```
docker-compose scale missive-storage-backend=2
```

The only problem is that if there is a new image, Docker Compose does not use it - it stubbornly uses the hash identical to the already running instance. I've checked `docker-compose scale --help` and there is nothing in there relating to forcing the use of a new image.

Now I *could* use an ordinary `docker run`, but then I'd have to replicate all the options I've set up for this service in my `docker-compose.yml`, and I don't know if something run outside of the Compose file would be understood as being part of that Compose application (e.g. would it be stopped with a `docker-compose down` despite having been started manually?).

It's possible also that later versions of Docker Compose may have more options in the scale function ([it has been merged with `up` anyway](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/scale/)).

What is the simplest way to get this feature?

(Aside: I appreciate there are a myriad of orchestration tools to do gentle reboots and other wizardry, and I will surely explore that bottomless pit when I have the time available. For now, I feel that writing a few scripts to do some deployment tasks is the quicker win.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this. Firstly I tried upgrading to Compose 1.9, but that didn't seem to offer the changes I need. I then bumped to 1.13, which is when `scale` becomes deprecated as a separate command, and appears as a switch to the `up` command.

As a test, I have an image called `missive-storage`, and I add a dummy change to the Dockerfile, so `docker ps` reports the name of the image in a running container as `d4ebdee0f3e2` instead (since `missive-storage:latest` has changed).

The `ps` line looks like this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                      NAMES
45b8023f6ef1        d4ebdee0f3e2           "/usr/local/bin/du..."   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                                                                   app_missive-storage-backend_1
```

I then issue this command (`missive-storage-backend` is the DC service name for image `missive-storage`):

```
docker-compose up -d --no-recreate --scale missive-storage-backend=2
```

which results in these containers:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                      NAMES
0bd6577f281a        missive-storage        "/usr/local/bin/du..."   2 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds                                                                   app_missive-storage-backend_2
45b8023f6ef1        d4ebdee0f3e2           "/usr/local/bin/du..."   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                                                                   app_missive-storage-backend_1
```

As you can see, this gives me two running containers, one based on the old image, and one based on the new image. From here I can just redirect traffic by sending a configuration change to the front-end proxy, then `stop` the old container.

Note that `--no-recreate` is important - without it, Docker Compose seems liable to reboot everything, defeating the object of the exercise.